# Spivak's proof that $\pi$ is irrational

Tags: calculus, pi

I'm reading chapter 16 of Spivak's Calculus, 4th edition, specifically proof that $\pi$ is irrational. Last part is unclear to me. He states that because
\begin{equation}
0 < \pi a^n f_n(x) \sin \pi x < \frac{\pi a^n}{n!}
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
0 < \pi \int_0^1 a^n f_n(x) \sin \pi x\,dx < \frac{\pi a^n}{n!}
\end{equation}
the part that is unclear to me is how did we conclude that the integral also obeys inequality.

Comment: Well, if $f(x)<C$, then what is the greatest possible value of $\int\limits_a^bf(x)dx$?

Comment: The absolute value of  the integral is bounded from above by the maximum of the function in the given interval multiplicated by the length of the interval, so we only need to show that the function is non-negative in the given interval to ensure that the integral is postivie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integration satisfies that if $0<f<g$ for two functions, then $$0<\int_If<\int_Ig$$ for any interval $I$. Applying this in the above case gives the second inequality.

Answer (score 1):

$(b-a)\min f\le\int_a^b f\le(b-a)\max f$.

Comment: I think both answers are useful but I accepted the other one because it was posted first